# how to get value dynamically in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table >
<tr align="left" id="progNav" class="width_150 margin_top20">


                    <core:forEach items="${fields}" var="field" >
                      <th value="${field.id} .." <core:if test="${field.id == fieldId }">id="bg_active_1" class="selected" </core:if>><a href="" class="bg_link1">${field.programmeField}</a></th>
                     </core:forEach>        

</tr>
</table>
```

How to get value for class="selected" or id="bg_active_1" ?
List
i have tried this :-

```
var fieldId=$('#progNav').parent().find('#bg_active_1').val();
var fieldId=$('#progNav').parent().find('th.selected').val();
var fieldId=$("#bg_active_1").val();
```

and many more but dont know why i every time get empty value ! i got muddled headed please help me out.

Comment: @SLaks ya its unique :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Do I get what i want from this..*

> var fieldId=$("#bg_active_1").attr('value');

Answer (score 3):

`$('.selected')` gets all elements with `class="selected"`

```
$('.selected').each(function(_, value) {
    // prints their HTML code
    console.log('.selected: '+$(value).html());
    // prints their (and children) text content
    console.log('.selected: '+$(value).text());
});
```

`$('[id="bg_active_1"]')` gets all elements with `id="bg_active_1"`

```
$('[id="bg_active_1"]').each(function(_, value) {
    // prints their HTML code
    console.log('[id="bg_active_1"]: '+$(value).html());
    // prints their (and children) text content
    console.log('[id="bg_active_1"]: '+$(value).text());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated very clearly in the documentation, `.val()` gets the value of a *form element*.
You don't have any form elements.

I suspect that you actually want to get the contents of the element; you probably want the `.text()` or `.httml()` functions.